# Stack around the variable ' ' was corrupted

Tags: c++

```
void GameBoard::enterShips()
{
    char location[1];
    int ships = 0;
    int count = 1;

    while(ships < NUM_SHIPS)
    {
        cout << "Enter a location for Ship " << count << ": ";
        cin >> location;
        cout << endl;

        Grid[location[0]][location[1]] = SHIP;
        ships++;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Im writing a battleship game. I have the board layouts working and the computers randomly generated ships. Now I am working on this method to prompt the user to enter coordinates for the ships When I run the program, it allows me to enter 5 ships. When I enter the 6th ship, it gives me this error.

> Stack around the variable location was corrupted.

Ive looked for answers online and have not found anything exclusive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead try `char location[1][2];` - that will give you a 1 by 2 array (indices: [0][0] and [0][1])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are prompting the memory address of `location` array to your user. You should ask location indices separately:

```
void GameBoard::enterShips()
{
    int location[2];
    int ships = 0;
    int count = 1;

    while(ships < NUM_SHIPS)
    {
        cout << "Enter a location for Ship " << count << ": ";
        cin >> location[0];
        cin >> location[1];
        cout << endl;

        Grid[location[0]][location[1]] = SHIP;
        ships++;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Notice `int location[2];` since an array of size 1 can only hold one element. I also changed the element type to int. Reading char's from the console will result in ASCII values, which are probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware you could do this.

Answer (score 12):

`location` is an array of a single `char`.
There is no `location[1]`.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> cin >> location;
> ```

`location` is an array of one `char`.  This can't succeed because when you read from a stream into a `char` array, a null terminator has to be added (which takes one character).  You will inevitably overrun the bounds of the array.

You can use a `std::string`, which will help you avoid any buffer overrun issues:

```
std::string location;
if (!(std::cin >> location)) {
    // handle input error
}
```

Note also that you probably need to convert the string representations of the numbers into numeric values.  You can easily do this by reading from the stream into two `int` objects instead:

```
int x_location, y_location;
if (!(std::cin >> x_location >> y_location)) { 
    // Handle input error
}

if (x_location >= X_DIMENSION || x_location < 0 ||
    y_location >= Y_DIMENSION || y_location < 0) {
    // Handle out-of-range error 
}

// use x_location and y_location
```

Answer (score 3):

You made the `location` variable only able to hold a single character.  You access it expecting it to hold at least 2 characters.  If you're using cin and expecting to read exactly two characters, a better method would be:

```
char locationX, locationY;
// ...
std::cin >> locationX >> locationY;
// ...
Grid[locationX][locationY] = SHIP;
```